# Как сделать изменения в базе с помощью Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wpf, sql-server

Я новичок в мире EF. Сделал подключение к базе данных по принципу Database First. Мне необходимо найти все вхождения "ул " в поле Школы.Адрес и заменить на "ул.". Я роде это сделал:

```
var context = new SchoolEntities();
foreach (var school in context.Школы)
{
  school.Адрес = school.Адрес.Replace("ул ", "ул.");
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Но выходит вот такая ошибка:

```
Исключение типа "System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException" возникло в EntityFramework.dll, но не было обработано в коде пользователя

Дополнительные сведения: Unable to update the EntitySet 'Школы' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <UpdateFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation.
```

Comment: `school.Адрес` — это строка? Строки в C# иммутабельны.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что автор пропал без вести 2 года назад :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov эээй, не надо этого делать. Я на месте).

Comment: ...вы хотите сказать что до сих пор проблема не решена?)

Comment: из-за того, что вы несколько раз меняли вопрос - правильного ответа тут нет.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, правильный ответ есть - тот, что я отметил. А именно: при переборе в `foreach` нельзя было применить метод-расширения, изменяющий значение переменной `var school`, куда я получаю элемент своей коллекции.

Comment: Это был ответ на первую версию вопроса. Кстати, Replace - это не метод-расширение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вместо

> school.Адрес.Replace("ул ", "ул.");

напишите

> school.Адрес = school.Адрес.Replace("ул ", "ул.");

и не забудьте про сохранение изменений в контексте

Answer (score 1):

context.SaveChanges();

Comment: Сделал как просили и выскочило: Unable to update the EntitySet 'Школы' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <UpdateFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation.

Comment: @derkode: То есть выходит, что `Школы` — не таблица, а view?

Comment: Нет это таблица в базе данных. На stackoverflow нашел вроде ответ:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583770/unable-to-update-the-entityset-because-it-has-a-definingquery-and-no-updatefu
Тут вроде говорят что это из-за того что у меня нет первичного ключа в таблице

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот этот код:

```
foreach (var school in context.Школы)
{
  school.Адрес = school.Адрес.Replace("ул ", "ул.");
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```